# How to access the ID or name in an object array which is in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to loop through to get all of the`id`s and `name`s from objects that are in arrays which is in another array. It's giving me 'undefined' even when I try to grab from 1 specific object using:

```
companies[0][0]['id']
```

This is my array:

[image]

[image]

Controller:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'companies', function($scope, companies) {

    $scope.companies = companies;
        console.log('companies', $scope.companies);

}]);
```

And I'm not even sure how to display/access it in HTML using expressions:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div ng-repeat="company in companies" class="list">
        <a href="#/{{ company.id }}" class="company-name">
        {{ company.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

Factory:

```
app.factory('companies', ['$http', function($http) {
    data = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        $http.get('https://examplepage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=50&page=' + i)
        .then(function(response) {
            data.push(response.data);
            console.log('data', data);
        },
        function(err) {
            return err;
        });
    }
    return data;
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit (upon question *Update*)

#### Problem

The way the interaction between controller(s) and your factory is designed is brittle and error prone. See your code commented below:

```
// factory
app.factory('companies', ['$http', function($http) {
    data = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        // you CANNOT control when this is going to return
        $http.get('https://examplepage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=50&page=' + i)
        .then(function(response) {
            // so this doesn't push to `data` synchronously, this DOES NOT
            // guarantee you when you return data, every response.data will be there
            data.push(response.data);
            console.log('data', data);
        },
        function(err) {
            return err;
        });
    }
    // this will always be returned empty ([], as you initialized it) because
    // the async responses (commented above) haven't arrived when this lint his hit.
    return data;
}]);

// controller
$scope.companies = companies; // so, companies will always be [] (empty array)
```

#### Solution

You should **strongly** consider changing the way you implemented the factory to something like this:

*The Idea*:

- Do not call the endpoint `x` (11) times for getting 550 items (50 * 11 times)
- Provide a function (`getCompanies`) in the factory  which accepts a `itemsPerPage` and a `page` parameter, this way you can get as much items as you want and in the page you want. i.e.: for getting 550 items you should call it: `companies.getCompanies(550);`
- From any controller which wants to get the companies call `companies.getCompanies`

*The Code*:

```
// factory
app.factory('companies', ['$http', function($http) {

    function fnGetCompanies(itemsPerPage, page) {
        var ipp = itemsPerPage || 50; // 50 default
        var page = page || 0; // 0 default page
        // return the promise instead of data directly since you cannot return the value directly from an asynchronous call
        return $http
            .get('https://examplepage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=' + ipp + '&page=' + page)
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    // and then return the data once the promise is resolved
                    return response.data;
                },
                function(err) {
                    return err;
                }
            );
    }
    // provide a `getCompanies` function from this factory
    return {
        getCompanies: fnGetCompanies
    }
}]);

// controller
// get 550 items starting from 0
companies.getCompanies(550, 0).then(function(companies) {
    $scope.companies = companies;
});
```

#### Additional notes

Remember [You cannot return from an asynchronous call inside a synchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/5640649)

---

### Original Post

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) first in order to convert the multi-array structure to a single array like this:

```
$scope.companies = companies.reduce(function(prevArr, currentArr) { return prevArr.concat(currentArr);}, []);
```

This converts a structure like this:

```
[
 [{id: 1, name: 'A'}, {id: 2, name: 'B'}, {id: 3, name: 'C'}],
 [{id: 4, name: 'D'}, {id: 5, name: 'E'}, {id: 6, name: 'F'}]
];
```

into this:

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "A"},{"id": 2,"name": "B"},{ "id": 3,"name": "C"},{"id": 4,"name": "D"},{"id": 5,"name": "E"},{"id": 6,"name": "F"}]
```

Simple demo:

```js
var companies =[
 [{id: 1, name: 'A'}, {id: 2, name: 'B'}, {id: 3, name: 'C'}],
 [{id: 4, name: 'D'}, {id: 5, name: 'E'}, {id: 6, name: 'F'}]
];

console.log(companies.reduce(function(prev, current) { return prev.concat(current);}, []));
```

Comment: That makes sense, but when I tried to execute it, I get an empty array when `$scope.companies` is console logged

Comment: @hkhuu then there is another problem, not stated in your original post, dude. By any chance is `$scope.companies = companies;` inside an asynchronous code?

Comment: I think it might be. It's pulling from a factory that I have in a separate js file. I've updated my original post with that code. Please take a look when you have a chance, thank you!

Comment: @hkhuu, well....wow... this is a completely different problem...let me see.

Comment: wow thank you so much for the breakdown! I really appreciate it!